# mysql multiple group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Good time! Tell me how to optimize this query and, if possible, unite it into one!

```
$query  = "SELECT external_source_id FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic WHERE ".$dateRange." GROUP BY external_source_id ORDER BY external_source_id ASC;";
$query .= "SELECT sources_id FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic WHERE ".$dateRange." GROUP BY sources_id ORDER BY sources_id ASC;";
$query .= "SELECT ip_country FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic WHERE ".$dateRange." GROUP BY ip_country ORDER BY ip_country ASC;";
$query .= "SELECT cidr FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic WHERE ".$dateRange." GROUP BY cidr ORDER BY cidr ASC;";

if (mysqli_multi_query($db, $query)) {
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($db)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $val = $row[0];
            if ($val != '') {
                $options .= '<li class="select_input_option_item" value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</li>';
            }
        }
        array_push($optionsArr, $options);
        $options = '';

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    if (!mysqli_more_results($db)) break;
} while (mysqli_next_result($db));} mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: When asking SQL query questions, always include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table referenced in your query, so we don't have to guess about the columns and indexes you may currently have. Also please let us know what your `$dateRange` variable includes. It's a mystery to us otherwise...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears your queries only need to get lists of distinct values in four columns.

Here's a way you can do this with one query:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT external_source_id ORDER BY external_source_id) AS external_source_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sources_id ORDER BY sources_id) AS sources_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip_country ORDER BY ip_country) AS ip_country,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cidr ORDER BY cidr) AS cidr
FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic 
WHERE $dateRange
```

The values will be returned in a single row, and each column will contain a string which is a comma-separated list of distinct values from each respective column in the database. You'll have to use PHP to [explode()](http://php.net/explode) each of these strings into an array.

The only way you might optimize this query is to create an index for your `$dateRange` condition to use. But you haven't included the value of `$dateRange` in your question, so I'll leave it to you to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Really, every query has a different group by and order by, so your best bet is to use `UNION`

```
$query = <<<QRY
SELECT external_source_id as ID
  FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic
  WHERE $dateRange
  GROUP BY external_source_id
  ORDER BY external_source_id ASC
UNION
SELECT sources_id ID
  FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic
  WHERE $dateRange
  GROUP BY sources_id 
  ORDER BY sources_id ASC
UNION
SELECT ip_country ID
  FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic 
  WHERE $dateRange
  GROUP BY ip_country
  ORDER BY ip_country ASC
UNION
SELECT cidr ID
  FROM smf_tds_unique_statistic
  WHERE $dateRange
  GROUP BY cidr 
  ORDER BY cidr ASC
QRY;
```

You should get the idea. The other way would be to use the date filter once and create an INDEXED `TEMP` Table and use THAT in your UNION. Depends how many records and how expensive the `$dateRange` filter is